# how to configure the php RAR Archive installer windows

Tags: php

```
<?php $rar_arch = RarArchive::open('filename.rar'); if ($rar_arch === FALSE)
die("Failed opening file");
$entries = $rar_arch->getEntries(); if ($entries === FALSE)
die("Failed fetching entries");
echo "Found " . count($entries) . " extract\location";
if (empty($entries))
die("No valid entries found.");
$stream = reset($entries)->getStream();
if ($stream === FALSE)
die("Failed opening first file");
$rar_arch->close();
echo "Content of first one follows:\n";
echo stream_get_contents($stream);
fclose($stream); ?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/rar.installation.php

Erorr is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'RarArchive' not found in C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\CSV\example.php on line 2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is are windows binaries here: http://pecl.php.net/package/rar

If you open the link you provided, then click "http://pecl.php.net/package/rar" link in the first line you get that page.

After that put the `.dll` to your php extensions dir and put the line

```
extension=php_rar.dll
```

to your `php.ini`

PS: I assumed the name of the `.dll` is `php_rar.dll`. Change it correspondingly to what is distributed in the downloaded archive.

Comment: Thank alot :), but am unable to set that RAR Extension ..please give me suggitions .....same error occured and also phpinfo() didn't shows RAR Extentions

Comment: @kim: first suggestion - explain in details what you've done.

Comment: @zerkms hmmm then why he listed php 7.2 dlls on download page : https://pecl.php.net/package/rar/4.0.0/windows

Comment: @user889030 report a bug then

Answer (score 0):

Besides downloading the correct dll and put it to the ext folder, configuring it in php.ini, you have also have to install `PEAR`.

The PHP_RAR has dependency to PEAR. See [this](https://pecl.php.net/package/rar) for more information. And you may install PEAR following [this link](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.getting.php).

If you install pear in windows, remember to user command-line tool with administrator privilege.